# How to delete certain properties from an object in an axios response in redux while calling an API server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am calling an API server from my redux project where I want to extract the data.The data in the API is in the form as shown below:

```
const defaultData = {
  categories: [
      {
        name: 'react',
        path: 'react'
      },
      {
        name: 'redux',
        path: 'redux'
      },
      {
        name: 'udacity',
        path: 'udacity'
      }
  ]
}
```

So, in my redux **"Actions"**, I am using axios to make the API call.The actions file is given below:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export const FETCH_CATEGORIES = 'fetch_categories';

let token;
if (!token)
  token = localStorage.token = Math.random().toString(32).substr(-8);
const API = 'http://localhost:3001';
const headers = {
                  'Accept' : 'application/json',
                  'Authorization' : 'token'
}

export function fetchCategories() {
  const URL = `${API}/categories`;
  const request = axios.get(URL,{headers});

  return dispatch => {
        return request.then((data) => {
          dispatch({
            type : FETCH_CATEGORIES,
            payload : data
          })
        })
  }
}
```

I am trying to save the result of the API call in the application state in my reducer.The **Reducer** for the categories looks like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { FETCH_CATEGORIES } from '../actions/categories_action';

export default function(state={}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
      case FETCH_CATEGORIES:
        return {categories: {...state.categories, ...action.payload}};

        default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

And I am using **combineReducers()** to combine all the reducers in my index file as shown below:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './PostsReducer';
import CategoriesReducer from './CategoriesReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    loading: false,
    posts: PostReducer,
    categories: CategoriesReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Then, in my component I am trying to show the data from the state.
So,when I try to console.log the value of the categories state, I get something like this as shown in the image below:

[image: value of categories]

But I just want the categories property where I get the three categories(I want to omit the config,headers,request properties).
I even tried something like: **console.log(this.props.categories.data.categories)**  ,but that gives me an undefined value.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: where and how are you logging to the console ?

Comment: @klugjo I am trying to log it inside my render method.Just give me a min, I will add the component file too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of this line `{categories: {...state.categories, ...action.payload}};`

Change that to `{categories: [...state.categories, ...action.payload.data.categories]};`

Comment: This is returning an empty object

Comment: I see, my bad. Change to {categories:[...state.categories, ...action.payload.data.categories]}